# Flask Application not returning javascript contents in html

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I have a little problem here with my  flask application

i have this html file that i have linked to some javascript files and if i open the html file with a browser it works fine with  the javascript codes.
Now if i use python flask and return the html file,only the html file is popped up while the JS part is not reflecting on the Web page?

I have linked my JS files to the html page and they are  in the same folder

any solutions?

```
head>
  <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="video.js"></script>
  <script src="zxing.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Probably `.js` files need to be moved to the `static/` subdirectory, and change the script tags to `src="{{ url_for('static', filename='name_of_file.js') }}"` for each.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new folder titled "Static". Inside that folder is where you store all your CSS files, JavaScript files, etc. So move your video.js, zxing.js and any other JavaScript file to the "Static" folder. Hope this helps, feel free to ask any questions!